# SpringBoot MVC - Warning: org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase : The JSSE TLS 1.3 implementation does not support authentication

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, tls1.2, tls1.3

A question about Spring Boot MVC with Tomcat and TLSv1.3

I used to have a Spring Boot MVC, Tomcat based web app, with very simple business logic, over ssl HTTPS.

Per security team review, I had to bump the TLS version from TLSv1.2 to TLSv1.3.

Thought is was very simple and could easily complete this task, I went to change my property:

```
server.ssl.enabled-protocols=TLSv1.2
```

to

```
server.ssl.enabled-protocols=TLSv1.3
```

However, since then, I am getting this on each application start up:

org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase   : The JSSE TLS 1.3 implementation does not support authentication after the initial handshake and is therefore incompatible with optional client authentication

What does it mean please?

Is it "dangerous"?

How to fix it please?

Thank you

Comment: Can you specify the version of Java and Spring Boot you use?

Comment: Java 11 and SpringBoot 2.4.2

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Post-Handshake Client Authentication is a TLSv1.3 extension defined in [RFC8446](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#section-4.6.2). But OpenJDK doesn't implement it and will not implement it. The [corresponding issue](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8206923) is marked as "Won't fix".

The warning is emitted by Tomcat in [SSLUtilBase.java](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/681f2afccc2f22ff5fc3d80ad7e77dbeecd083b2/java/org/apache/tomcat/util/net/SSLUtilBase.java)

```
if (enabledProtocols.contains(Constants.SSL_PROTO_TLSv1_3) &&
        sslHostConfig.getCertificateVerification() == CertificateVerification.OPTIONAL &&
        !isTls13RenegAuthAvailable() && warnTls13) {
    log.warn(sm.getString("sslUtilBase.tls13.auth"));
}
```

The `isTls13RenegAuthAvailable()` method is defined in [JSSEUtil.java](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/681f2afccc2f22ff5fc3d80ad7e77dbeecd083b2/java/org/apache/tomcat/util/net/jsse/JSSEUtil.java)

```
@Override
protected boolean isTls13RenegAuthAvailable() {
    // TLS 1.3 does not support authentication after the initial handshake
    return false;
}
```

To remove this warning you can either set [CertificateVerification](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http.html#SSL_Support_-_SSLHostConfig) in Tomcat's SSLHostConfig to `NONE` or to `REQUIRED`. You can do it through the Spring Boot property [server.ssl.client-auth](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.2/reference/htmlsingle/#server.ssl.client-auth) which take the values `NONE`, `WANT` and `NEED`.

If you don't use client certificates, set it to `NONE`. If you use client certificates, check that each client can authenticate itself correctly with the `NEED` value. If you leave it as it, the only risk is that client that use post-handshake authentication will not be able to authenticate.

If you really need post-handshake client authentication, you will have to use another TLS implementation than [JSSE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/security/java-secure-socket-extension-jsse-reference-guide.html#GUID-93DEEE16-0B70-40E5-BBE7-55C3FD432345). You can either use a reverse proxy such as [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/), [NGINX](https://www.nginx.com/), [Traefik](https://traefik.io/traefik/) or use [Tomcat’s native](http://tomcat.apache.org/native-doc/) bindings for [APR](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/apr.html)/[OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/). There is an interesting article you can read about this: [Tomcat Native / OpenSSL in Spring Boot 2.0](https://medium.com/@crueda/tomcat-native-openssl-in-spring-boot-2-0-a341ad07471d)

== Update 5th April 2023 ==

After a [message](https://mail.openjdk.org/pipermail/security-dev/2022-August/031568.html) on the OpenJDK security-dev mailing list, the [OpenJDK issue](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8206923) has been reopened and the "Won't fix" label has been removed. But the TLS 1.3 Post-handshake authentication is still not implemented in the OpenJDK.

Comment: Very clear answer, upvoted. Its just on my side, maybe I don't understand it fully. You are correct, if I set the server with  server.ssl.client-auth=NEED + server.ssl.enabled-protocols=TLSv1.3, the error disappears! (upvote). However, the requirement I got from my teams is to leave one way TLS server.ssl.client-auth=WANT + server.ssl.enabled-protocols=TLSv1.3, in which the message still stays. But I am reading thought the documentations linked

Comment: Thanks. Using server.ssl.client-auth=NEED + server.ssl.enabled-protocols=TLSv1.3, is not possible with JSSE. This is the reason of the warning. If you want to fulfill your requirements you will have to choose another implementation. See my updated answer.